# Can I make UIPinchGestureRecognizer scale an image faster than normal?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, scale

I'm making an app that deals with scaling images using the UIPinchGestureRecognizer, which works fine right now. The problem is that it is difficult to make the images small because your fingers get too close together. Can I speed up how fast the image scales to solve this? (The image would be smaller by the time your fingers are touching).

This is the code I found in a tutorial that works fine, but I admit I don't completely know how it works:

```
func pinchedView(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer){

    backgroundImage.bringSubviewToFront(sender.view!)

    sender.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sender.view!.transform, sender.scale, sender.scale)
    sender.scale = 1.0
}
```

I have tried setting sender.scale to other values but it completely ruins the whole thing and touching the image makes it disappear. I don't know why I'm being down voted either. :(

Comment: Why not use a zooming scroll view and let it do the work for you?

Comment: Im not sure what that would do in this case. The user is manipulating images to move around and place differently an imageview which is then saved.